# Getting Windows 8 Live ID: GetPrincipalNameAsync() returns empty string

Tags: c#, windows-8, liveid

I'm trying to use the method

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync()
```

to get Windows Live ID, but it returns an empty string, anyone knows why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you confirmed that someone is signed in / that the app has declared the necessary permissions in the manifest (project properties)? Not on my dev machine so I can't check the names, but that'd be a good place to start.